# If there is a tag for quadcopters, would we benefit from having a tag for hexacopters and octocopters?

Tags: discussion

My thinking on this question is that a quadcopter is a subset of all multirotor drones. And if we have one subset of all multirotors, we may benefit from having the most common types such as hex-, octo-, tri-, and heli-.

Answer (score 7):

I think we should. There are certain specialties in each field, for example setting up the motor mixing in Betaflight.

However, this opens up the door to loads of different options, for example X8, Y6 copters etc.

Comment: We can create these as the need arises, i.e. when questions about them are asked.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the tags are for?

If someone asks a question about an odd configuration, then it will be tagged in case somebody else comes along with a similar question.

Comment: @BenWilson Are people adding useful tags? OK, yes, I will go read a few posts and judge for myself. I will see you all back in a day or two. But I am not particularly optimistic. I hope I am wrong about tags.

Comment: I want to say something about tags.  Is there reason to hope?  When I first joined and tried to post a question, several tags I wanted to use did not exist. And, I was too new to create a new tag. And I am so new to SE that I did not know where the tag list is. Maybe this group is still so new that a bit of patience on my part will pay dividends. But I am not too sure about anything on the internet getting better with time. I have seen too many cases of stuff on the internet remaining about the same as it was.... just about the same as it was at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Seems reasonable. Even though for many people these are functionally the same, on a fundamental level they're very different. The addition of rotors changes the dynamics and permits regimes of flight which are simply not possible with drones with fewer rotors.

Maybe `multirotors` tags could be joined by `quad-`, `hexa-`, `octo-`. Those would be optional, and would only make sense when the question is specific to that architecture. For instance, asking how many motors a multirotor can lose and still maintain full 3-D control isn't sensible if you have 4 motors or fewer.